# Ajax Post data and then return the result

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, mailchimp

Hey I want to take the ID of a Mailchimp list and send it to the controller. So the controller takes the ID and gives back all the information about the right Mailchimplist

But I get all lists, so the GET function is not taking the data when the list id gets Posted

Ajax code in the blade

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
               $('select').on('change',function () {
                   var mailchimplist = $(this).val();
                   alert(mailchimplist);
                   $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "/fetch/mailchimp/pos",
                       data: {mailchimplist : mailchimplist },
                       success: function(msg) {
                           console.log(mailchimplist);
                           $('#autosavenotify').text(msg);
                       }
                   })
               });
           });
           $(document).ready(function() {
               $('select').on('change',function () {
                   $.ajax({
                       url: "/fetch/mailchimp/pos",
                       type: 'GET',
                   })
                       .done(function (data) {
                           console.log(data);
                       })
                       .fail(function () {
                           console.log('Failed');
                       });
               })
           });
```

My controller, So i want to Post here the mailchimplist id and then return the results back to my blade

```
    public function mailchimp(Request $request){

        $mailchimp = new Mailchimp("MyAPI");

        $client = new \MailchimpMarketing\ApiClient();
        $client->setConfig([
            'apiKey' => $mailchimp->apikey,
            'server' => $mailchimp->request->getExpApikey()['1'],
        ]);

        $response = $client->campaigns->get("$request->mailchimplist");

        return response()->json($response, 200);
    }
```

Web.php

```
    Route::any('/fetch/mailchimp/pos', 'IndexController@mailchimp');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this you dont't need that

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
               $('select').on('change',function () {
                   $.ajax({
                       url: "/fetch/mailchimp/pos",
                       type: 'GET',
                   })
                       .done(function (data) {
                           console.log(data);
                       })
                       .fail(function () {
                           console.log('Failed');
                       });
               })
           });
```

Change mailchimplist to msg because that in the "Function('msg')"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
               $('select').on('change',function () {
                   var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'); //add this line of code
                   var mailchimplist = $(this).val();
                   alert(mailchimplist);
                   $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "/fetch/mailchimp/pos",
                       data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, mailchimplist : mailchimplist }, //add _token field also
                       success: function(msg) {
                           console.log(mailchimplist);
                           $('#autosavenotify').text(msg);
                       }
                   })
               });
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, the first glitch is csrf token.

Put this line in the head section of your blade file.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Edit your ajax code as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
               $('select').on('change',function () {
                   var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'); //add this line of code
                   var mailchimplist = $(this).val();
                   alert(mailchimplist);
                   $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "/fetch/mailchimp/pos",
                       data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, mailchimplist : mailchimplist }, //add _token field also
                       success: function(msg) {
                           console.log(mailchimplist);
                           $('#autosavenotify').text(msg);
                       }
                   })
               });
           });
           $(document).ready(function() {
               $('select').on('change',function () {
                   $.ajax({
                       url: "/fetch/mailchimp/pos",
                       type: 'GET',
                   })
                       .done(function (data) {
                           console.log(data);
                       })
                       .fail(function () {
                           console.log('Failed');
                       });
               })
           });
```

[Read More about csrf protection in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf)

Comment: If I look at the concole logs I still get all the campaings from mailchimp, I only want the one we have send in with Ajax